# count the nodes of a child in the firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a structure like this in firebase:

[image]

Inside the node 'postagens-curtidas', I need to count this childrens and save this value at the 'qtdCurtidas' node, as the photo shows.

Is there a way to make this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
final long count;
DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
ref.child("postagens-curtidas").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            count = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

This is how you get the total number of children nodes.

Assuming you have the key where qtdCurtidas is saved. You can save it as follows

```
ref.child("postagens-curtidas").child("Your Key Here").child("qtdCurtidas").setValue(count);
```

Comment: Variable `count` is accessed from within inner class and needs to be declared final or effectively final.